# How to add up duplicate name values and divide the totals in different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I made a Google Spreadsheet to use for as a database on my site, but I'm not quite familiar with the formulas Excel/Google Spreadsheets are using.

Situation: (Column A) I've got a column with the names (there are 3 different names), (Column B) a column with the starting KM, (Column C) a column with the ending KM, then three following columns with the totals per person and at last a column with the total of all the three persons. Link to spreadsheet is down below.

Question: So my question is, I need to calculate the difference between the values in column B and C and put the outcome (identical per person) in their belonging columns (column E to G). Is this possible?

Keep in mind that the rows A to D keep getting extended every time the car gets driven again.

Link to Spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qncUWs_Qm98OoSDdrRkE5yRw34fzIhLSEkIDkvxRLN0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on having a separate column per person, this is the formula you should put under each person's name, e.g. in E2:

```
=sumif($B:$B; E$1; $D:$D)-sumif($B:$B; E$1; $C:$C)
```

This can then be copied to F2 and G2.

But to future-proof in case there would be more drivers, put the following formula somewhere else (perhaps on a separate sheet):

```
=query(Blad1!B:D; "select B, sum(D)-sum(C) where B <> '' group by B"; -1)
```

[image]